# TYPO3 and generated random ID for div

Tags: php, html, css, typo3

I've TYPO3 page, and when I'm looking into structure my eyes are bleeding...

```
<div id="c6880" class="csc-default">...</div>
<div id="c6924" class="csc-default">...</div>
<div id="c6336" class="csc-default">...</div>
<div id="c6066" class="csc-default">...</div>
<div id="c6058" class="csc-default">...</div>
```

There is possibility to change that names of ID or adding to "csc-default" for example class "col-md-12" ?

Comment: You should see a doctor about those bleeding eyes. The source code looks fine to me. If you want to change the rendering of the HTML output of TYPO3 nearly everything is possible. But you need to tell us, what version of TYPO3 you are using and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those id values correspond to ids of content elements on the page. If you use TYPO3 <= 7.6 or TYPO3 7.6 with css_styled_content, you can go to Web>Templates and TypoScript Object Browser. There type `id="c` in the search field. You will see where it is defined in TypoScript. You can unset or change it like you wish.

If you use TYPO3 7.6 with fluid_styled_content, it is more complicated: you will need to override it with your own fluid template (search for the same string inside fluid_styled_content system extension).

In general, it is not worth spending time. Leave it as is.

Answer (score -1):

Simple by using jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.csc-default').addClass('col-md-12');
    });
```

Don't forget to include jQuery library if missing.